# Solve a linear equation with many variables using only 1 and -1

Tags: linear-algebra

For a program I am writing, I would find it useful to find the least possible positive solution to a linear equation, using only -1 and 1 for roots.

For example...

```
0.25a + 0.5b + 0.75c + 1d + 2e = 0
```

When

```
a = -1, b = 1, c = 1, d = 1, e = -1
```

However, if we take the example

```
3a + 1b + 5c
```

It is still beneficial to know that

```
a = -1, b = -1, c = 1
```

Provides the least possible positive solution (1)

How can I algorithmically find these solutions? I would rather not use a brute force technique, my goal is to optimize the program by finding the solutions.

Forgive me for the lack of tags, I have no idea what kind of math this relates to, if any at all.

Comment: This is something like zero-one linear programming which in general is NP-complete.

Comment: In particular, this is the partition problem: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_problem

Comment: You probably want to read the answers to this closely related question: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/123670/all-possible-linear-combinations-of-positive-half-integers-with-coefficients

Comment: What do you mean by "positive" solution, when you allow the variables to take on the value $-1$?

Comment: @GerryMyerson: judging by OP's example, they mean the least positive value that the left-hand side can take.

Comment: Thanks guys, I ended up solving this with a semi-brute force method. I was hoping for a mathematical solution, but my method should be quicker than what I had before.